# Cassette teeth design

Tags: gears, cassette

I'm new to the bicycles scene and was trying to 3D draw a bicycle.

I'm currently trying to draw an 11 speed 11-30T cassette but I quickly noticed that the design of the teeth of the gears are quite advanced and thus that piqued my interest.

From a friend I hear that there are books and papers that discuss the shape of the teeth and they also have equations used to determine the shape using the pitch and roller diameter dimensions from the chain.

I tried looking for these books or any relevant information on these teeth designs but to my surprise, it seems that this info is really hard to find on the internet.

So my next strategy to find this information is by asking others! So if anyone has any information on this or has a website/book/technical report where I can find more info about this topic please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Have you tried searching for free CAD files?  I found a [primitive 6-speed Shimano cassette](https://grabcad.com/library/bicycle-sprocket-cassette-shimano-1) in a quick search, but that might be old enough not to have the ramps you're talking about.

Comment: While shapes can be observed, measured and copied, the reasons behind them is complex. Much of the  information you are looking for will be propitiatory knowledge keep secret by the manufacturers.

Comment: @DavidW Hi, thanks for the reply and welcoming! i have actually searched for some online but sadly have not found file formats to see how they actually drew the gears (i use autodesk software). However i did find this [link](http://www.gearseds.com/files/design_draw_sprocket_5.pdf) that details formulas and stuff on motorcycle teeth design and this is exactly what i would like but then for bikes ofcourse

Comment: @mattnz i was thinking that aswell :( i may have to reverse engineer some of this then :/

Comment: The basic design goes back probably 200 years, and is a simple matter of geometry.  But starting about 1975 bike designers began modifying the design, mainly on the sides, to make shifting "crisper".

Comment: Frank Berto's book The Dancing Chain has a few pages on sprocket designs and means to improve smooth shifting, such as Shimano's HyperGlide (p.366-368 in the 2013 update). My guess is that for disclosure of the fine-detail you have to search the patent literature, which is usually awful reading. Try Google's patent search.

Comment: A quick search with Google patents showed many relevant patents, often including technical drawings https://patents.google.com/?q=(bicycle+sprocket+wheel)&patents=false

Comment: Tangentially, it may help to explain why you want to do this?  I doubt you're making your own cassette?  Feel free to [edit] your question rather than commenting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I hear that there are books and papers that discuss the shape of the teeth and they also have equations used to determine the shape using the pitch and roller diameter dimensions from the chain...  if anyone has any information on this or has a website/book/technical report where I can find more info about this topic please let me know.

This is a huge topic I'm going to bucket the conversation into two groups.
**1.** Information on products currently being manufactured.
**2.** General roller sprocket and roller chain design - this is the best source of detailed information. Google and/or search Amazon books "roller chain design" or "roller sprocket design".

**1. Information on currently manufactured products.**
Bicycle drive train makers (Shimano and others) have spent a great deal of money trying to make chains and cogs that shift better in hopes of giving them a competitive advantage in the market place. The details of their design are proprietary and patented. They will not publish enough details for you to re-create their designs.

There are people who have spent the time reverse engineering products.

For example:

Peter Verdone has a page that details a [Shimano hyperglide 9 spd](https://www.peterverdone.com/hyperglide/) cassette interface.
[image]

Konstantin Shemyak spent some time examining the teeth of hyperglide sprocket teeth and has [posted his findings](http://konstantin.shemyak.com/cycling/HG/hyperglide.html).
[image]

GRABCAD has drawings of [cassettes](https://grabcad.com/library/tag/shimano?page=1&time=all_time&sort=recent&query=shimano%20cassette) and [chains](https://grabcad.com/library/tag/shimano?page=1&time=all_time&sort=recent&query=shimano%20chain).
[image]
[image]

Here is a deep dive into some [Shimano chainring designs using information from the patent office from BIKERUMOR!](https://bikerumor.com/2016/02/01/is-shimano-losing-teeth-to-make-lighter-better-shifting-chainrings/).
[image]

Chasing the patent trail - Google has a nice [patent search engine](https://patents.google.com/). Here is an example of a "[bicycle sprocket assembly](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20120225745)"
[image]

**2. General roller sprocket and roller chain design**
The roller chain / roller sprocket drive mechanism is over 100 years old. If you look for information that is not specific to current bicycle drive trains and generalize to sprocket and chain design you can find a world of technical information on the web an machinist handbooks like [this document on Gears Educational Systems](http://www.gearseds.com/files/design_draw_sprocket_5.pdf).

Or an article on [designing a single speed cog](http://trail70engineer.blogspot.com/2017/09/designing-singlespeed-cog-getting-to.html) as just two examples of the mountain of information available.
[image]

Comment: +1 for quantity of information and underlying 'here, let me Google that for you' vibe.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Thanks. Searching can be frustrating if you don't know what words to use. My goal was to be helpful.